# Backbone where returns empty in fetch callback

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, titanium, titanium-alloy

I'm having an odd error where a backbone where function (Titanium Alloy, kinda homogeneous) returns empty while the fetch method returns a list of models. Ive checked over and over again, I tried putting the where function in the success callback of the fetch method but STILL it results in an unresolvable error

```
Alloy.Collections.favorites.fetch({
     success: function(collection) {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(collection));
          console.log(self.get('id'));
          var favorite = collection.where({
              jobId: self.get('id')
          });
          console.log(JSON.stringify(favorite));
});
```

The above output is:

```
[{"jobId":5162179,"dateAdded":1414590144,"candidateId":99,"id":19},{"jobId":5161302,"dateAdded":1414588983,"candidateId":99,"id":17},{"jobId":5161437,"dateAdded":1414588785,"candidateId":99,"id":16}]
5161437
[]
```

How can the above happen? How can somebody reproduce this? Is the collection being occupied or is it a bug within Titanium Alloy? This process is part of a databind on a view (view A) and this exact code works on a different part where the only difference is that view A is not directly influenced by changes in the collection.

Any help? Is this even possible with backbone? I cant get my head around this

Comment: Try `console.log(favorite);` ie. not stringifying it

Comment: When you serialize collection as a whole by `JSON.stringify`, [`toJSON`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-toJSON) method is invoked implicitly which converts collection to JSONable array. But when you try to serialize result of `collection.where`, this causes error because [`collection.where`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-where) returns **array of models** which cannot be serialized to JSON directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

APPARENTLY the .where function strictly compares 2 values (`===` operator) and the id i gave was in the form of a `string` while the id within the collection was an `integer`. Too bad the backbone documentation doesnt state this information

Comment: I made the same mistake last week :)